# Vaadin Grid Ids

Tags: java, vaadin, jbehave

I am using Vaadin Grid and a BeanContainer.

In order to facilitate testing witj JBehave i would like to set Id for certain element on each row programmatically.

so that the result is like:

```
<td id="MyField_row_1" class="v-grid-cell v-grid-cell-focused" colspan="1" style="height: 30px; width: 430px;">copyOf_PP_kulan</td>

<td id="MyField_row_2" class="v-grid-cell v-grid-cell-focused" colspan="1" style="height: 30px; width: 430px;">copyOf_PP_kulan</td>
```

etc.

I can't find a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for IDs, could you not simply traverse your DOM in another way?

```
tr class="v-grid-row"
    td class="v-grid-cell"
        MyField_row_1
```

Vaadin will not generate any IDs in their HTML-DOM and maybe writing some code to "hack in" IDs (which then need to be tested as well) is a bit too much?